# Github Line Comments in Task Navigation IDEA IntelliJ

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, task

Using Github and IntelliJ IDEA w/Task Context Integration to my Github repo.

If another user creates in-line file-commit comments, or comments in general, to the pull request, am I able to see these inside of IDEA? I was thinking this may be part of a `Projects(config) | Tasks | Navigation | Configured annotations...` But they are empty and I'm not sure what my syntax would be to bring these in.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Why not asking the plugin author? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7241?pr=idea